# Hot to respond js in rails if action has no form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, private-pub

I trying make notification system and have problem

I need publish notification to the view with this:
track_activity.js.erb

```
<% publish_to "/notifications/new" do %>
  $("#activity").append("<%= j render(@activity) %>");
<% end %>
```

and my application_controller with action track activity

```
def track_activity(user, trackable, action = params[:action], author = current_user)
    @activity =  Activity.create! user: user, trackable: trackable, action: action, author: author
  end
```

and i using this methos every time when oher user create something like this

comment_controller.rb

```
def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
        @comment.user = current_user
        if @comment.save
            track_activity @post.user, @comment
            redirect_to post_path @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

How to attach track_activity.js.erb every time when rails call track_activity action?
respond_to in track_activity action doesn't help

Comment: What you actually want to achieve? 
You want to render js and redirect also ?

Comment: I want push notification in real time with private_pub this code work alert works but doesn't render @activity :)